# Cannot handle this data type

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Consider the following code

```
one_map = (one_map - minVglobal) / (maxVglobal - minVglobal)
one_map *= 255
PIL_att = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(one_map))
```

The error due to last line is

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 48), |u1

one_map is a float np array. I need to convert into integers. So, I used np.uint8.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> one_map = np.array([i/10 for i in range(11)])
>>> one_map *= 255
>>> one_map
array([  0. ,  25.5,  51. ,  76.5, 102. , 127.5, 153. , 178.5, 204., 229.5 , 255. ])
>>> one_map = one_map.astype(np.uint8)
>>> one_map
array([  0,  25,  51,  76, 102, 127, 153, 178, 204, 229, 255], dtype=uint8)
```